# ClearQuest order by

Tags: clearquest

I am using Clear Quest 7.0.1.4 and have created a Personal Query.  However, I can't figure out how to get the Query to automatically order by one of my fields.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the "Display editor" tab for your query.  There you will see all the fields that are displayed in that query.  To sort a specific field click the check box in the "Sort" column.  This will rotate through your options of A->Z, Z->A and no sort.

If you wish to sort by multiple fields select the sort you want for each field.  Then in the "Sort Order" column specific the order in which they should be sorted.  The field with a sort order of 1 will be sorted first followed by the field that has a sort order to 2.  This continues for each field that has a sort order.  Fields that do not have a sort order are sorted at the end.

Do note that any columns that do not have a sort order or if multiple columns have the same sort order they will be sorted in the order that they are listed.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time in ClearQuest 7.1.2. I don't remember if 7.0.1.4 is that different. I do know it's a different GUI, but I don't remember if this particular part was changed.

The way you do it in ClearQuest 7.1.x is by setting the value of the "sort" column (next to the field name column), setting it to 1 will indicate that the field has the most order priority, 2 follows and so on...

I hope it helps.